# Getting Invalid number of parameters for "undefined" when deploying smart contract

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to deploy my first Voting contract on the testRPC and the below is my code.. for some reason it's complaining when I come to deploy.

The error seems to be from the arguments parameter. I tried passing an empty array and it said "Got 0 expected 1!". I tried passing just one name and it says "value.forEach" is not a function.

```
Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compiledCode = solc.compile(sourceCode)
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface)
VotingContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition)
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].bytecode

VotingContract.deploy({
    data: byteCode, 
    arguments:['Joseph','Sean','Matthew']
}).send({
    from: '0x00D1AE0A6fC13B9ecdefA118B94cF95ac16D4ab0', 
    gas: 4700000
})
.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
.then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this for contracts that need constructor arguments

```
var bytecodeWithParam = MyContract.new.getData(
    param1,
    param2,
    { data: compiledByteCode });
```

It is this bytecodeWithParam that you paste into the "Byte Code" field. If you look at it in detail, you will see param1 and param2 32-byte packed at the end.

Another Example

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// instantiate by address
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);

// deploy new contract
var contractInstance = MyContract.new([constructorParam1] [, constructorParam2], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});

// Get the data to deploy the contract manually
var contractData = MyContract.new.getData([constructorParam1] [, constructorParam2], {data: '0x12345...'});
// contractData = '0x12345643213456000000000023434234'
```

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: I forgot to write that I was using web3.js v1.0 in my question. I appreciate your answer however I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539031/vm-exception-while-processing-transaction-out-of-gas) more helpful since the question is using v1.0. Thank you for your help still!

Answer (score 6):

In the migrations, add your args in the deployer.

```
// Deploy a single contract with constructor arguments
deployer.deploy(A, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

where A is your smart contract, arg1, arg2 etc are the arguments

This is mentioned in the documentation: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-